# PIP and EASY_INSTALL installed but not working

Tags: python-2.7, pip, easy-install

[image]

check the image and tell me why error continues and what is the solution

Comment: Try doing this  :  `pip --no-cache-dir install flask`

Comment: try this as well but same error returns

Comment: How about this:  `sudo -H python -m pip install --upgrade flask` ? If that doesn't work then delete everything inside : `~/.cache/pip/` , don't delete pip folder itself  and then try again.

Comment: Failed Again Same Issue but now im going to try “rm ~/.cache/pip/*”

Comment: Not found any Folder ~/.cache :(

Comment: How about trying to install from apt-get : `sudo apt install python3-flask` ?

Comment: yes its working but why pip is not working

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/185315/discussion-between-rahul-bharadwaj-and-harry1992).